# Why is a neural network based classifier better than a bayesian network?

Tags: neural-network

I am trying to find a good classification approach for my problem of classifying multiple customer records with missing, truncated or wrong data values into different customer categories i.e. to classify one or more customer record and see if it belongs to the same customer or to a different customer. Why should I use a neural network for this and not a bayesian net? My professor said that a neural network is the best approach to it.

Answer (score 3):

It depends very much on the type of data you are trying to classify. Neural networks are typically good at continuous data whereas bayesian nets tend to work better with discrete data. Of course, continuous data can be discretised by putting it into buckets, but that's another layer of complexity that you may not need.

Both approaches (theoretically) cope well with missing, truncated and incorrect data.

I'd suggest that you ask your professor *why* they think a neural network would be a better approach.

Comment: Thanks. But how can one decide what kind of a problem space it is?

Comment: @Artika: Unfortunately, that's the hard part and it's the sort of thing you learn with experience. You need to try a bunch of algorithms on a bunch of problems (or read a **lot** of conference papers) and see what works and what doesn't. There are some general guidelines, like I mentioned in the answer, but ultimately it's very hard to know ahead of time which algorithm will perform better.

Comment: Thanks Cameron. It was still quite helpful

Comment: Hi,I have another doubt. If my output is taking only two values i.e. a Match or a Non Match which activation function will work better- sigmoid or purelin?

Comment: @Artika: I don't know, sorry. It's been a few years since I've done much neural network stuff.